# Keyup is working only after clicking on "submit"

Tags: javascript, keyup

I want to apply colors to input field while typing in it, However it is applied only after I click on the button "submit". I could not paste my code here, so I have attached it.[enter image description here][1]

```
`const form=document.querySelector('form');
 const submit=document.querySelector('submit');
 const pattern=/^[a-zA-Z]{6,12}$/;
 const feedback=document.querySelector('.feedback');

 form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
 e.preventDefault();
 if(pattern.test(form.username.value)){
    feedback.textContent='Nice :)';
 }else{feedback.textContent='Too Sad :('}
 })

 form.username.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
 if(pattern.test(e.target.value)){
    form.username.setAttribute('class', 'success')}
    else{form.username.setAttribute('class', 'error')}
  })`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 1):

In the console, wich error is showing?

Your problem is because you are listening an incorrect value, you have to add the listener to the input field instead input field value.

EX:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const username =  form.username;
   
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(){  
      //Code
  });

username.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  console.log('keyup');
});
```

Tell my if it's clear for you.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, I a confused coz if I change code this way:

form.username.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
    if(usernamepattern.test(e.target.value)){
        console.log('good');
    }else{
        console.log('bad');
    }
});
It works, but it does not work with colors...